# Loading a new vim colorscheme

Tags: vim, terminal, iterm2

I am trying to load a new vim colorscheme without any luck.

I have downloaded the railscasts.vim scheme and have put this in:

```
~/.vim/colors
```

My .vimrc looks like this:

```
colorscheme railscasts
syntax on 
set number
```

I don't see any change in the vim syntax hightlighting however?

I'm running vim from the terminal on OSX 10.6.

**EDIT:**
I have also tried running it on iTerm2 with the colorscheme set to xterm-256 but it is still not displaying correctly.

**EDIT:** After deleting that theme and swapping it for the [this one](https://github.com/davidkariuki/sexy-railscasts-256-theme), everything looks great now. This states clearly as well its 256 compatible. The other theme did too so no idea why it didn't work but iTerm set to 256 with a 256 compatible theme seems to be the easiest setup on OS X if you are on 10.6 or earlier.

Comment: have you followed the install-instructions at http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2175?

Comment: I haven't looked at it yet, but maybe railscasts colorsheme doesn't work well in terminal windows (some colorschemes are gvim only)

Comment: Well every colorscheme I've tried hasn't worked. I've been trying one by one from the list here: http://www.vimninjas.com/2012/08/26/10-vim-color-schemes-you-need-to-own/. Am I loading them in the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that your terminal is not correctly set for 256 colors. I see that the color scheme is intended for use in the gui look at its source code, but that most of the colorings have terminal alternatives, but require 256 colors.

Make sure your terminal is set for 256 colors. If it is, if you do

```
echo $TERM
```

you should get something back like

```
xterm-256color
```

Comment: I get: 'xterm-color'. I need to change this obviously?

Comment: It will be a setting somewhere in your terminal application to turn on or force 256 colors.

Comment: I have an option in my terminal preferences where it is declared as xterm-color but no option in the dropdown for xterm-256color. What I do have is: ansi, dtterm, rxvt, vt52, vt100, vt102, and xterm.

Comment: Okay I've downloaded iTerm2 that has xterm-256 color and it appears to be loading the scheme somewhat but the colors are still not right (dont match color scheme screenshots). $TERM is now echoing xterm-256color however.

Comment: correct. the colors in the terminal are not the same as those in the gui. you only get 256 colors in terminal so colors schemes like this one designed for gui will never look quite right in a terminal.

Comment: It doesn't look remotely right! It appears to be still using an 8 or 16 color profile even though $TERM is printing to xterm-256.

Comment: I have deleted that railscasts theme and looked for another 256 compatible theme and it worked fine. Thanks for the help!